# how to use tailwind and grid?

Tags: css, reactjs, grid, responsive

How can I get this same result using tailwind.
I am working with tailwind more precisely with GRID, when I want to use `auto-fit` in tailwind it generates conflict.

`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use it as an [arbitrary value](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support) like so `grid-cols-[repeat(auto-fill,minmax(300px,1fr))]` just make sure that there are no spaces in the declaration. Here is an example on Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/uUAyIIknoB